# Visual Stodio - compiling project for 32-bit or 64-bit system

Tags: compilation, project, 32bit-64bit, visual-studio-2015

When I compile some kind of a project in Visual Studio 2015, does it compile it for 32-bit or 64-bit systems? Is there any way to find out? How do I control which version it compiles between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the menu bar, you can see the current platform for which the project will be compiled.
[image]

If you press the little arrow, you can open the Configuration Manager and create new target platforms.

The Configuration Manager is also available under Build ---> Configuration Manager.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found it